# Trying to install Gstreamer 1.0 on 12.04 - is the PPA of the backports gone?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, ppa

I am trying to install Gstreamer 1.0 on a new 12.04 installation. When I try to add the PPA I get this:

```
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gstreamer-developers/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Trying to install the package and I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0*
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0*'
```

I loaded Synaptic and can't seem to find any listings for Gstreamer1.0

How else can I access get the package installed?

Answer (score 2):

Came to this post for the same reason.  Ended up finding this ppa that has the gstreamer 1.0 package

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable